# How can restrict Rich Text Editor Properties (Fonts, Font Sizes, Color etc.) in Ribbon in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, ribbon

I would like to restrict Rich text editor features which placed on Ribbon Toolbar while an user is editing an page.
For example, only Arial and Times New Roman fonts and font size 10, 11 and 12 will be displayed.

Answer (score 5):

Follow this guide from Waldek, it is for 2010 but should work just as well from 2013: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/consistent-content-authoring-sharepoint-2010-rich-text-editor/

Basically:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" HasInitialFocus="True" 
AllowFonts="false" AllowTextMarkup="false" 
AllowParagraphFormatting="false" PrefixStyleSheet="mv-" MinimumEditHeight="400px" runat="server"/>
```

use this attributes to lock down properties.

The `PrefixStyleSheet` enables you to only show your custom styles like

```
H2.mv-Element-H2
{
  -ms-name:"Heading 2";
   font-size:12px;
}
```

But please read the article to get a full understanding

Comment: This article I have already seen but it disables all font groups by using AllowFonts=false property.
This is not the solution that I want.

Comment: Well then do not set it to false, and then use PrefixStyleSheet and some custom css classes..

Comment: I think I found finally a good article which explains the customization on RTE in detail.
Here is the link:

http://blog.avtex.com/2012/06/08/custom-text-styles-for-sharepoint-rich-text-editors/

Comment: blog.avtex.com link is dead.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20121018110828/http://blog.avtex.com/2012/06/08/custom-text-styles-for-sharepoint-rich-text-editors